# Using <linux/types.h> in user programs, or <stdint.h> in driver module code...does it matter?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm developing a device driver module and associated user libraries to handle the `ioctl()` calls.  The library takes the pertinent info and puts it into a struct, which gets passed into the driver module and unpacked there and then dealt with (I'm omitting a lot of steps, but that's the overall idea).

Some of the data being passed through the struct via the `ioctl()` is `uint32_t` type.  I've discovered that that type is defined in `<stdint.h>` AND `<linux/types.h>`.  So far I've been using `<linux/types.h>` to define that value, including down in the user libraries.  But I understand it is bad form to use `<linux/*.h>` libraries in user space, so if I remove those and use `<stdint.h>` instead, then when my driver module includes the struct definition, it will have to be including `<stdint.h>` also.

It seems to me that the point of `<linux/types.h>` is to define types in kernel files, so I'm not sure if that means using `<stdint.h>` is bad idea there.  I also found that when trying to compile my driver module with `<stdint.h>`, I get compilation errors about redefinitions that won't go away, even if I replace all instances of `<linux/types.h>` with `<stdint.h>` (and put it on the top of the include order).

1. Is it a bad idea to use linux/*.h includes in user-space code?
2. Is it a bad idea to use `<stdint.h>` in kernel-space code?
3. If the answers to both of those is yes, then how do I handle the situation where a structure containing `uint32_t` is shared by both the user library and the driver module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Is it a bad idea to use linux/*.h includes in user-space code?

Yes, usually.  The typical situation is that you should be using the C-library headers (in this case, `stdint.h` and friends), and interface with the C library though those user-space types, and let the library handle talking with the kernel through kernel types.

You're not in a typical situation though.  In your case, you're *writing the driver library*.  So you should be presenting an interface to userspace using `stdint.h`, but using the `linux/*.h` headers when you interface to your kernel driver.

So the answer is no, in your case.

> 1. Is it a bad idea to use stdint.h in kernel-space code?

Most definitely yes.

See also: http://lwn.net/Articles/113349/

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed length integers in the Linux kernel**

The Linux kernel already has fixed length integers which might interest you. In v4.9 under `include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h`:

```
typedef signed char s8;
typedef unsigned char u8;

typedef signed short s16;
typedef unsigned short u16;

typedef signed int s32;
typedef unsigned int u32;

typedef signed long long s64;
typedef unsigned long long u64;
```

LDD3 has a chapter about data sizes as well: https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch11.pdf

LDD3 mentions there that  the best `printk` strategy is to cast to just cast to the largest integer possible with correct signedness: `%lld` or `%llu`. `%ju` appears unavailable under the `printk` formatting centerpiece `lib/linux/vsprintf.c`.