# Identifying kernel space in the preprocessor?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing the header of a kernel module. The header is known to the module, but also used by callers in user space. This is a problem, because some types used should be included from different files depending on whether the header is currently in user or kernel space (or so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541536/using-linux-types-h-in-user-programs-or-stdint-h-in-driver-module-code-does-i) question makes me think).

I don't want to maintain two separate header files, so I've been thinking of a solution like this:

```
#ifndef IN_KERNEL
#include <stdint.h>
#else
#include <linux/types.h>
```

With IN_KERNEL being defined somewhere in my kernel code. Is there a preprocessor constant that already does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/113349/), it seems that an existing constant used for this purpose is `__KERNEL__`.

```
#ifndef __KERNEL__
#include <stdint.h>
#else
#include <linux/types.h>
#endif
```

Comment: And the common practice now is to maintain two headers, one for user space (UAPI), and another for in kernel use. Although the example given by OP is a bit confusing.

Comment: @0andriy: If by *UAPI* you mean header files under `include/uapi`, this is not quite true: These headers are used **both** by kernel code and user one. E.g. types defined in [include/uapi/linux/btrfs.h](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/include/uapi/linux/btrfs.h) are used by btrfs filesystem (implemented in the kernel).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I know. I simplified for the sake of shorter comment. In any case there is still confusion what OP is trying to do with them (based on example `stdint.h` is not **kernel** related header at all).

Comment: Example uses `stdint.h` as a **non-kernel** header (`#if*n*def`) and `linux/types.h` as kernel one. I see no confusion in that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, *I'm writing the header of a kernel module.* This is a contradiction. The part in the example shouldn't be in the kernel header even if it is a UAPI one.

Comment: @0andriy: Don't get your point. Code in the example could perfectly be part of a header under `include/uapi`, which is accessible for a kernel module during compilation, and which can be installed, so user can access it too.

Comment: No, it can’t (technically yes, though it would be abuse of a common sense). One more time and I am going to rest my case, *stdint.h* has nothing to do with kernel. It must not be in a **kernel** part of headers.